# OData Method Routing Returns 404 not found

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have added OData V4 to my Web Api 2 app.
registered OData route in WebApiConfig register method before default route:

```
//defining the routes for our OData service
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: GenerateEdmModel());
```

---

```
 private static IEdmModel GenerateEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Media>("Media");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

**MediaController.cs**

```
[EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ApiMedia> GetMedia(ODataQueryOptions<Media> query )
    {
       *querying and returning media*      
    }
```

but when I call `localhost:80880/odata/media`
returned response says:

**The resource cannot be found.**
**Requested URL: /odata/media**

calling `localhost:80880/odata` returns this:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:80880/odata/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"Media","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Media"
    }
  ]
}
```

so whats wrong here?
 (does it looking for a controller named odata?)
I followed the tutorial on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant believe but I should type **mysite.com/odata/Media** not **mysite.com/odata/media**

Answer (score 0):

You will quickly find this feature. I was looking for 2 days. Uppercase url request depends on the entityset name

```
builder.EntitySet<Media>("Media"); // if the changed to "media" will work !
```